# How to create and pass an object in body of a function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn React and I have the login function which is shown below:

```
function login(username,password) {
 const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({username,password})
};

 return fetch('http://localhost:8090/login', requestOptions)
  .then(handleResponse)
  .then(response => {
    return response;
 })
}
```

As you can see I pass two separate parameters in the body of my function. Which is called in my component from here:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
 ...
 userService.login(this.state.username,this.state.password)
  .then(response => {
    if (response === 'false') {
     this.setState({loading: false});
    } else {
         localStorage.setItem('jwt-token', response);
         this.setState({error: ''});
         const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/"}};
         this.props.history.push(from);
       }
    });
}
```

So the thing is that I don't know how to create an object and pass it as a parameter in my function's body. Any help?

Comment: Which function are you trying to pass an object to?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to replace the signature of your `login` function to accept an object with `username` and `password` instead of passing two separate parameters. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexeyKureev yeah, for example I want to have an object = {username,password} and then pass it in my function like function login() { body: object } and not pass every parameter like the above in the body section.

Answer (score 1):

Your current function states that it takes two arguments: `username` and `password`:

```js
function login(username, password) {...}
```

What you need to do, is to replace these two parameters with one parameter (for example, `loginCredentials`) and use it accordingly in the body of your function:

```js
function login(loginCredentials) {
 const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify(loginCredentials)
};

 return fetch('http://localhost:8090/login', requestOptions)
  .then(handleResponse)
  .then(response => {
    return response;
 })
}
```

In this case, your `handleSubmit` might pass an object (like `this.state`) to the login function:

```js
userService.login(this.state)
```

**Note:** I'd recommend you to be explicit about the arguments you call your function with. For example, your state might contain unrelated to login information. It wouldn't make much sense to pass this information to the `login` function (as it won't process them), so instead of passing the entire `this.state` to `userService.login`, you might come up with a more neat approach:

```js
const loginCredentials = {
  username: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password,
};

userService.login(loginCredentials).then(...);
```

Comment: Ok I understand till here, but how do I create an object separate from `this.state`? I don't want to use `this.state`. Do I have to use always `this.state` to pass as an object? Sorry if I'm bad but I'm really new to React coming from Angular...

Comment: It is absolutely fine! That's what we're here for :) I've edited my answer to include a block that elaborates on `this.state` usage and how you can compose a separate object (`loginCredentials`) to use only a part of the information from your state

Comment: Ok now I understood completely. You just create locally an object and you pass it as a parameter. That's what I need! Thanks! So silly I didn't think of it...

Comment: No worries! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
const Credentials = {
  username: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password,
};


handleSubmit(event) {
  userService.login(Credentials)
   .then(response => {
     if (response === 'false') {
      this.setState({loading: false});
     } else {
          localStorage.setItem('jwt-token', response);
          this.setState({error: ''});
          const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: "/"}};
          this.props.history.push(from);
        }
     });
 }
```